# Sending '@' (at sign) character in AS3 socket for FTP Login

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, character-encoding, ftp, ftp-client

I'm trying to create a FTP Client in AS3.
It works well with almost all my ftp hosts, but I'm not able to login in hosts in wich I have an "@" (at commercial) character inside the username.
It seems a character encoding error.

I'm sending the string in this way:

> ```
> ftp_username = "aaaaa@bbbbb.ccc"
> s.writeUTFBytes("USER " + ftp_username + "\n");
> ```

but I'd never got a 331 response (Username Accepted) from the FTP server.

ps: i tried replacing '@' char with '%40' or '+' without success.

Comment: In your test you removed the @ but not the "." dot. Anyway You should always encode data before sending to the server. Especially user inputted data. So I would suggest you base64 encode the data before sending and then base64 decode on the server side.

Comment: @The_asMan: you should NOT be base64 encoding any data in this case. That is the completely wrong thing to do for FTP. The `@` character is perfectly legal in the `USER` command. Some FTP proxies require it to know which username to use for which remote hostname.

Comment: @vannyn: can you use Telnet to log in succesfully to the same FTP server using the same username with the `@` character in it? If AS3 and Telnet cannot both login, then it is not an encoding problem, it is a server problem. Not all server support email addresses as usernames.  As for replacing `@` with `%40` or `+`, such replacements do not apply to FTP.

Comment: @remy-lebeau-teamb: Yes, I tried login with telnet and it worked without problems sending USER aaaaa@bbbbb.ccc.

Comment: @The_asMan I agree with Remy, no base64 encoding for ftp communications.

Comment: I've solved. It wasn't the "@" char, but the problem was that the ftp server was running Windows and I had to send "\r\n" for new lines.
Thank you the same.

Comment: @vannyn I think the spec for FTP explicitly defines end of line as `\r\n`. But it's been a while since I read it. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959

Comment: @32bitkid I was on error because all other ftp server I have are running linux and only \n was working well :/

Comment: @vannyn At the end section 4.1, it talks about endings for FTP commands and cites the Telnet protocol, and then says that you can assume that to mean <CRLF>. The Telnet spec also confirms this. In fact, most internet protocols  (HTTP, STMP, FTP, IRC) mandate the use of <CRLF>, but recommend recognizing a lone <LF> as a line terminator as well. So its not a "windows" issue, but a very strict FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of Section 4.1 of the [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), which deals with the FTP protocol standards, it defers to the Telnet protocol and the Telnet eol code.

To quote from the RFC:

> The File Transfer Protocol follows the specifications of the Telnet protocol for all communications over the control connection.  Since the language used for Telnet communication may be a negotiated option, all references in the next two sections will be to the "Telnet language" and the corresponding "Telnet end-of-line code". Currently, one may take these to mean NVT-ASCII and `<CRLF>`.  No other specifications of the Telnet protocol will be cited.

Then again in [RFC 1123, Section 3.3.1](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/31.htm) references the correct end-of-line as `<CRLF>`:

> The Telnet protocol defines the sequence CR LF to mean "end- of-line". For terminal input, this corresponds to a command- completion or "end-of-line" key being pressed on a user terminal; on an ASCII terminal, this is the CR key, but it may also be labelled "Return" or "Enter".

Then it goes into a discussion about the ambiguity of line endings on different platforms. And says that allowances should be made for `<CR NUL>`, or `\r\0`, but again says that `<CRLF>` should be the default.

On the Wikipedia article for [Newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), also discuses the issue, and says:

> Most textual Internet protocols (including HTTP, SMTP, FTP, IRC and many others) mandate the use of ASCII CR+LF (0x0D 0x0A) on the protocol level, but recommend that tolerant applications recognize lone LF as well. In practice, there are many applications that erroneously use the C newline character '\n' instead (see section Newline in programming languages below). This leads to problems when trying to communicate with systems adhering to a stricter interpretation of the standards; one such system is the qmail MTA that actively refuses to accept messages from systems that send bare LF instead of the required CR+LF.

So stick with `\r\n` and you'll be fine...

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. My wandering was due to the fact that probably some ftp linux servers also accept \n (without \r).